# Matrix element of two operators, where one does not commute with the operators of the basis kets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

If I am considering 2 operators A and B and an initial basis $|F,m_F\rangle$ , where F is the total angular momentum operator of the two systems. While assuming that operator A does commute with $\vec F^2$,$F_z$,$S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$ and B does not.
How can I find a matrix element of $A+B$ in the basis $|F,m_F\rangle$?

I thought of taking the CGC and trying to find how kets  $|F,m_F\rangle$ are related to $s_1,s_2,m_{s_1},m_{s_1}$ where B commutes. And than I could find how B is expressed in the basis $|F,m_F\rangle$?

Would this be a logical and viable way?

Comment: What are your operators $A$ and $B$ ? How are they defined initially ?

Comment: @SolubleFish Here is the solution but for when we want to find the matrix element in the uncoupled tensor basis http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/qm1/modules/m10/problems3.htm

Now I want the opposite. I was able to derive what is written here and understand it. But now how do I go from the uncoupled tensor basis to the coupled one? I am thinking of the CGC, but I am not sure